# Html links do not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am updating the many of my website to use jquerymobile collapsible menu. I added jquery scripts but now when I click on the menu links they do not work.

At first I was getting this error message

[image]

I added

```
$(document).bind('mobileinit',function(){

    $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
});
```

and the error went away but the links still do not work.

This is the website code

```css
<!-- custom styles-->

html,body{
 /*height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;*/
 /*background-color: #FF9900;*/
 /*font-family: 'Lucida Calligraphy', Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;*/


}



@media (min-width: 769px){

body{
 background: url(images/florence2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
 

}
 #left{
  /*height: 100%;*/
  width: 50em;
  float: left;
  /*background-color: rgb(255,153,0);*/
  background-image: url(images/background.png);
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 25px;
  
 }

 .container{
  margin-left: 10%;
 }

 .logo img{
  height: 16em;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
 }

 #sidebar{

  width: 10em;
  height: 20em;
  /*margin-left: 15px;*/
  margin-top: 40px;
  line-height: 30px;
  clear: both;
  float: left;

  /*color: #ba2817;*/

 }
 .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: transparent;
}
 #side{

  /*font: 22px/1.7em "Lucida Calligraphy",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;*/

  color: #FFF;
  text-align: left;

 }

 #sidebar li{
  list-style-type: none;
  border-bottom: 1px;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  /*border-bottom-color: rgb(52, 52, 52);*/
  border-bottom-color: rgb(255,255,255);
  text-align: left;
  font: 17px/2em 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;

 }

 #address{
  width: 29%;
  margin-left: 5em;
  color: #FFF;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
 }

 #hours{
  width: 30%;
  margin-left: 5em;
  color: #FFF;
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
 }
 #menu li{
  list-style-type: none;
  /*font-size: 15px; */
  font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  color: #FFF;
  margin-left: 7em;
  text-align: center;


 }
 #menu h3{
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
 }
 #menu p{
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
 }

 #menu #sub {
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
 }
 #social li{
  text-decoration:none; 
  border:none; 
  display: inline-block;

 }
 #social{
  text-align: center;
 }
 #mobsocial{
  
  display: none;
  
 }

 a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
 }

 a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
 }

 a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
 }

 a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
 }

 #moto{

  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
 }
 #moto{
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-top: none;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-color: #FFF;
  font: 28px/1.2em 'Felipa', cursive;

 }

 #description{
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: justify;
  margin-left: 9em;
  margin-right: 2em;
  padding-top: 1.5em;
  width: 65%;
  font: 22px/1.625em 'Felipa', cursive;





 }

 #footer{
  height: 30px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 2em;
  font: 15px/1.625em 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
 }
 .map_canvas {
  width: 450px;
  height: 300px;
  margin-left: 15em;
  margin-top: 3em;
  margin-bottom: 5em;

 }
 #mobile{
  display:none;
 }

 #links img{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 3.5em;
  margin-left: 2em;
 }

 #tittle{
  font: 18px 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
 }
 #tittle p{
  font: 13px 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
 }


 #links{
  width: 80%;
  float: right;
 }


}

@media (min-width: 599px) and (max-width: 768px){

 body{
 background: url(images/florence2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;

}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: transparent;
}
 #left{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  /*float: left;*/
  /*background-color: rgb(255,153,0);*/
  background-image: url(images/background.png);
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-right: auto;
  
 }



 .logo img{
  height: 16em;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
 }

 #sidebar{

  width: 10em;
  height: 20em;
  /*margin-left: 15px;*/
  margin-top: 40px;
  line-height: 30px;
  clear: both;
  float: left;

  /*color: #ba2817;*/

 }
 #side{

  /*font: 22px/1.7em "Lucida Calligraphy",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;*/

  color: #FFF;
  text-align: left;

 }

 #sidebar li{
  list-style-type: none;
  border-bottom: 1px;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  /*border-bottom-color: rgb(52, 52, 52);*/
  border-bottom-color: rgb(255,255,255);
  text-align: left;
  font: 15px/2 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;

 }

 #address{
  width: 29%;
  margin-left: 5em;
  color: #FFF;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
 }

 #hours{
  width: 30%;
  margin-left: 5em;
  color: #FFF;
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
 }
 #menu li{
  list-style-type: none;
  /*font-size: 15px; */
  font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  color: #FFF;
  margin-left: 7em;
  text-align: center;


 }
 #menu h3{
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
 }
 #menu p{
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
 }

 #menu #sub {
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
 }
 #social li{
  text-decoration:none; 
  border:none; 
  display: inline-block;

 }
 #social{
  text-align: center;
 }
 #mobsocial{
  
  display: none;
  
 }

 a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
 }

 a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
 }

 a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
 }

 a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
 }

 #moto{

  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
 }
 #moto{
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-top: none;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-color: #FFF;
  font: 24px/1em 'Felipa', cursive;

 }

 #description{
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: justify;
  margin-left: 9em;
  margin-right: 2em;
  padding-top: 1.5em;
  width: 65%;
  font: 22px/1.6em 'Felipa', cursive;

 }

 #footer{
  height: 30px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 2em;
  font: 13px 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
 }
 .map_canvas {
  width: 350px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: 15em;
  margin-top: 3em;
  margin-bottom: 5em;

 }
 #mobile{
  display:none;
 }

 #links img{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 3.5em;
  margin-left: 2em;
 }

 #tittle{
  font: 14px 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
 }


 #links{
  width: 80%;
  float: right;
 }

 .navbar-collapse {
    
    
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 45px;
    overflow-x: visible;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.1);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.1);
    }

    .navbar-default .navbar-collapse, .navbar-default .navbar-form{
     border-color: transparent; 
    }

}

@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 598px){

 html{
  min-height: 100%;
 }

 body{
 background: url(images/florence3.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
 height: 100%; 
 
}


.navbar-default .navbar-collapse, .navbar-default .navbar-form {
    
    border-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-collapse{
 clear: both;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.nav>li>a {
    
     padding: 0px 0px; 
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-collapse .in {
    
    padding-left: 45px;
    
}

ul{
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
}
 #left{
  /*height: 100%;*/
  width: 100%;
  /*float: left;*/
  /*background-color: rgb(255,153,0);*/
  background-image: url(images/background.png);
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-right: auto;
  
 }



 .logo img{
  height: 90px;
  width: 100%; 
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  
 }

 #sidebar{
  
  width: 98%;
  height: 100%;
  /*margin-top: 40px;
  line-height: 30px;
  clear: both;
  float: left;*/
  
  

 }
 #side{

  color: #FFFFFF;
  width: 100%;
  
  
 }
 
 ul.side{
  padding-left: 0px;
  text-align: center;
 }

 .side li:before{
  /*content: "/ ";
  color: #FFF;*/
 }

 .side li:first-child:before{
  content: " ";
 }

 #sidebar li{
  margin-top: 1em;
  /*display: inline-block;*/
  display: list-item;
  text-decoration: none;
  font: 16px 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; 

 }

 #moto{
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0.1em;
  border-top: none;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-color: #FFF;
  font: 16px/0.1em 'Felipa', cursive;
  

 }

 #description{
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: justify;
  width: 96%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  font: 16px/1.3em 'Felipa', cursive;
  
  
  
 }
 

 #address{
  width: 45%;
  margin-top: 0.8em;
  margin-left: 1em;
  color: #FFF;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 9px;
  float: left;
 }

 #hours{
  width: 35%;
  color: #FFF;
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 9px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  
 }
 #menu li{
  list-style-type: none;
  /*font-size: 15px; */
  font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  color: #FFF;
  /*margin-left: 7em;*/
  text-align: center;

  
 }
 #menu h3{
  text-decoration: underline;
  padding-top: 0.3em;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
 }
 #menu #fh3{
  text-decoration: underline;
  padding-top: 1.8em;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
 }
 #menu p{
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;

 }
 #menu ul{
  padding-left: 0px;
 }

 #menu #sub {
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
 }
 #social li{
  display: none;
  /*text-decoration:none; 
  border:none; 
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 3px;
  list-style-type: none;
  */
 }
 #social{
  display: none;
  /*
  text-align: center;
  */
 }
 #mobsocial li{
  
  text-decoration:none; 
  border:none; 
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
  
  
 }
 #mobsocial{
  
  text-align: center;
  
 }
 ul#mobsocial{
  padding-left: 0px;
 }
 a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
 }

 a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
 }

 a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
 }

 a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
 }

 #moto{
  
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
 }


 #footer{
  height: 5em;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 2em;
  font: 10px 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
 }
 .map_canvas {
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;

 }
 #desktop{
  display:none;
 }


 #links img{
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  margin-top: 10px;  
  margin-left: 1em;

 }

 #tittle{
  font: 11px 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
 }

 
 #links{

  margin-top: 3em;
  margin-left: 1em;
 }

}






/*! normalize.css v3.0.1 | MIT License | git.io/normalize */

/**
 * 1. Set default font family to sans-serif.
 * 2. Prevent iOS text size adjust after orientation change, without disabling
 *    user zoom.
 */

html {
  font-family: sans-serif; /* 1 */
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 2 */
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Remove default margin.
 */

body {
  margin: 0;
}

/* HTML5 display definitions
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Correct `block` display not defined for any HTML5 element in IE 8/9.
 * Correct `block` display not defined for `details` or `summary` in IE 10/11 and Firefox.
 * Correct `block` display not defined for `main` in IE 11.
 */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
main,
nav,
section,
summary {
  display: block;
}

/**
 * 1. Correct `inline-block` display not defined in IE 8/9.
 * 2. Normalize vertical alignment of `progress` in Chrome, Firefox, and Opera.
 */

audio,
canvas,
progress,
video {
  display: inline-block; /* 1 */
  vertical-align: baseline; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Prevent modern browsers from displaying `audio` without controls.
 * Remove excess height in iOS 5 devices.
 */

audio:not([controls]) {
  display: none;
  height: 0;
}

/**
 * Address `[hidden]` styling not present in IE 8/9/10.
 * Hide the `template` element in IE 8/9/11, Safari, and Firefox < 22.
 */

[hidden],
template {
  display: none;
}

/* Links
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Remove the gray background color from active links in IE 10.
 */

a {
  background: transparent;
}

/**
 * Improve readability when focused and also mouse hovered in all browsers.
 */

a:active,
a:hover {
  outline: 0;
}

/* Text-level semantics
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Address styling not present in IE 8/9/10/11, Safari, and Chrome.
 */

abbr[title] {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted;
}

/**
 * Address style set to `bolder` in Firefox 4+, Safari, and Chrome.
 */

b,
strong {
  font-weight: bold;
}

/**
 * Address styling not present in Safari and Chrome.
 */

dfn {
  font-style: italic;
}

/**
 * Address variable `h1` font-size and margin within `section` and `article`
 * contexts in Firefox 4+, Safari, and Chrome.
 */

h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0.67em 0;
}

/**
 * Address styling not present in IE 8/9.
 */

mark {
  background: #ff0;
  color: #000;
}

/**
 * Address inconsistent and variable font size in all browsers.
 */

small {
  font-size: 80%;
}

/**
 * Prevent `sub` and `sup` affecting `line-height` in all browsers.
 */

sub,
sup {
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

sup {
  top: -0.5em;
}

sub {
  bottom: -0.25em;
}

/* Embedded content
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Remove border when inside `a` element in IE 8/9/10.
 */

img {
  border: 0;
}

/**
 * Correct overflow not hidden in IE 9/10/11.
 */

svg:not(:root) {
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Grouping content
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Address margin not present in IE 8/9 and Safari.
 */

figure {
  margin: 1em 40px;
}

/**
 * Address differences between Firefox and other browsers.
 */

hr {
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 0;
}

/**
 * Contain overflow in all browsers.
 */

pre {
  overflow: auto;
}

/**
 * Address odd `em`-unit font size rendering in all browsers.
 */

code,
kbd,
pre,
samp {
  font-family: monospace, monospace;
  font-size: 1em;
}

/* Forms
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Known limitation: by default, Chrome and Safari on OS X allow very limited
 * styling of `select`, unless a `border` property is set.
 */

/**
 * 1. Correct color not being inherited.
 *    Known issue: affects color of disabled elements.
 * 2. Correct font properties not being inherited.
 * 3. Address margins set differently in Firefox 4+, Safari, and Chrome.
 */

button,
input,
optgroup,
select,
textarea {
  color: inherit; /* 1 */
  font: inherit; /* 2 */
  margin: 0; /* 3 */
}

/**
 * Address `overflow` set to `hidden` in IE 8/9/10/11.
 */

button {
  overflow: visible;
}

/**
 * Address inconsistent `text-transform` inheritance for `button` and `select`.
 * All other form control elements do not inherit `text-transform` values.
 * Correct `button` style inheritance in Firefox, IE 8/9/10/11, and Opera.
 * Correct `select` style inheritance in Firefox.
 */

button,
select {
  text-transform: none;
}

/**
 * 1. Avoid the WebKit bug in Android 4.0.* where (2) destroys native `audio`
 *    and `video` controls.
 * 2. Correct inability to style clickable `input` types in iOS.
 * 3. Improve usability and consistency of cursor style between image-type
 *    `input` and others.
 */

button,
html input[type="button"], /* 1 */
input[type="reset"],
input[type="submit"] {
  -webkit-appearance: button; /* 2 */
  cursor: pointer; /* 3 */
}

/**
 * Re-set default cursor for disabled elements.
 */

button[disabled],
html input[disabled] {
  cursor: default;
}

/**
 * Remove inner padding and border in Firefox 4+.
 */

button::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/**
 * Address Firefox 4+ setting `line-height` on `input` using `!important` in
 * the UA stylesheet.
 */

input {
  line-height: normal;
}

/**
 * It's recommended that you don't attempt to style these elements.
 * Firefox's implementation doesn't respect box-sizing, padding, or width.
 *
 * 1. Address box sizing set to `content-box` in IE 8/9/10.
 * 2. Remove excess padding in IE 8/9/10.
 */

input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
  box-sizing: border-box; /* 1 */
  padding: 0; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Fix the cursor style for Chrome's increment/decrement buttons. For certain
 * `font-size` values of the `input`, it causes the cursor style of the
 * decrement button to change from `default` to `text`.
 */

input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  height: auto;
}

/**
 * 1. Address `appearance` set to `searchfield` in Safari and Chrome.
 * 2. Address `box-sizing` set to `border-box` in Safari and Chrome
 *    (include `-moz` to future-proof).
 */

input[type="search"] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield; /* 1 */
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box; /* 2 */
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

/**
 * Remove inner padding and search cancel button in Safari and Chrome on OS X.
 * Safari (but not Chrome) clips the cancel button when the search input has
 * padding (and `textfield` appearance).
 */

input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

/**
 * Define consistent border, margin, and padding.
 */

fieldset {
  border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  margin: 0 2px;
  padding: 0.35em 0.625em 0.75em;
}

/**
 * 1. Correct `color` not being inherited in IE 8/9/10/11.
 * 2. Remove padding so people aren't caught out if they zero out fieldsets.
 */

legend {
  border: 0; /* 1 */
  padding: 0; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Remove default vertical scrollbar in IE 8/9/10/11.
 */

textarea {
  overflow: auto;
}

/**
 * Don't inherit the `font-weight` (applied by a rule above).
 * NOTE: the default cannot safely be changed in Chrome and Safari on OS X.
 */

optgroup {
  font-weight: bold;
}

/* Tables
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Remove most spacing between table cells.
 */

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <title>Firenze Trattoria</title>


 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/Logo.ico">
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Felipa' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> 

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).bind('mobileinit',function(){
        
        $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
    });
</script> 
 <script src="jquery.mobile-1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  
</head>
<body >

 <div class="container">


  <div id="left">

    <div class="logo">
      <img src="images/Logo.png">
    </div>

    <div id="moto">
      
    </div>

    <div id="sidebar" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target=".user-dropdown" >
     
      <nav class = "navbar navbar-default" role = "navigation" style="background-color:transparent; border:none;">
      
      <div class = "navbar-header">
      <button type = "button" class = "navbar-toggle pull-left" 
         data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = "#navbar-collapse" style="background-color:black; margin-left: 43px;">
         
         <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
         <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
         <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
      </button>  
      <!--<a class = "navbar-brand" href = "#">Menu</a> -->
   </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id = "navbar-collapse">
      
      <ul class="side nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="index.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="Menu.html">Menu</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="RestaurantWeekMenu.html">
            <div style="line-height:20px">Restaurant Week Menu</div>
          </a>
        </li>
        <!--<li><a href="Wine.html">Wine</a></li>-->
        <li><a href="Gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="Directions.html">Directions and Gift Cards</a></li>

      </ul>
    </div>
    </nav>
    
      
   </div>

   <div id="description">

    <p>
      
    </p>

  </div>



  <div id="footer">
    
    <div>
      <ul id="mobsocial">
       <li ><a href="http://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g60954-d5498230-Reviews-Firenze_Trattoria_Salem-Salem_Massachusetts.html" target="blank"><img width="20px" height="20px" src="images/tripadvisor-icon.png"></a></li>
       <li ><a href="http://www.foursquare.com/v/firenze-trattoria/5245ed6811d2bfaa1b282bd5" target="blank"><img width="20px" height="20px" src="images/foursquare.png"></a></li>
       <li ><a href="http://www.yelp.com/biz/firenze-trattoria-salem" target="blank"><img width="20px" height="20px" src="images/yelp.png"></a></li>
       <li ><a  href="https://www.facebook.com/firenzesalem" target="blank"><img width="20px" height="22px" src="images/facebook.png"></a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</div> 
</div>

<!--main container-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems like you need to spin up a simple local server, so you will access it as 127.0.0.1 or localhost instead of file:///...

Comment: i have tried both of those suggestions and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of poking around it seemed that data-toggle="dropdown" was causing the problem.